# How to add a class to a loaded content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, load

I am loading a content and I would like to add a class to that content.

Main content

```
<div id="notice">

</div>
```

Content to be loaded.

```
<p>Se v&aring;r <br />
siste <span>KAMPANJE</span></p>
<p>V&aring;re <span>TILBUD</span></p>
```

My jQuery so far.

```
$('#notice').load('notice.asp'); // this loads ok.

// but this does not
$("#notice p:even").addClass("bluenotice noticecommon");

$("#notice p:odd").addClass("greennotice noticecommon");
```

Can I addClass() to a loaded content?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to execute that in the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) callback, since the content is loaded later (when the server responds with data), like this:

```
$('#notice').load('notice.asp', function() {
  $("#notice p:even").addClass("bluenotice noticecommon");
  $("#notice p:odd").addClass("greennotice noticecommon");
});
```

Or a bit faster in older browsers:

```
$('#notice').load('notice.asp', function() {
  $(this).find("p:even").addClass("bluenotice noticecommon");
  $(this).find("p:odd").addClass("greennotice noticecommon");
});
```